# Vue SPA - call method from any component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm working on a notification functionality that can be called from any component. It's a simple `Vuetify` `v-snackbar`.

In `App.vue`

```
   <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
   <v-snackbar :value="showNotification" :multi-line="false">{{
                notificationText
              }}
   </v-snackbar>
```

and method

```
methods:{
 notify(text){
   this.notificationText = text
   this.showNotification = true
 }
}
```

this obviously work inside `App.vue` but I'd like to call `notify` from any component. How can I do that? I use `router`

Answer (score 0):

In main.js add the global properties :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.prototype.$notificationText = ''
Vue.prototype.$showNotification = false
....
```

App.vue

```
 <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
   <v-snackbar :value="$showNotification" :multi-line="false">{{
                $notificationText
              }}
   </v-snackbar>
```

then any component do :

```
methods:{
 notify(text){
   this.$notificationText = text
   this.$showNotification = true
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state manager (vuex) for this functionality.

```js
// store.js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    showNotification: false,
    notificationText: ''
  },
  mutations: {
    changeNotificationState (state, value) {
      state.showNotification = true
    },
    changeNotificationText (state, value) {
      state.notificationText = value
    }
  },
  actions: {
    notify({ commit }, text) {
      commit('changeNotificationState', true)
      commit('changeNotificationText', 'some text')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
   <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
   <v-snackbar :value="$store.state.showNotification" :multi-line="false">{{
                $store.state.notificationText
              }}
   </v-snackbar>
```

Now from every component in your app you can call the notification function like this:

```js
this.$store.dispatch('notify', 'notification text')
```